# mysql dynamic cursor

Tags: mysql, cursors

Here is the procedure I wrote- Cursors `c1` & `c2`. `c2` is inside `c1`, I tried declaring `c2` below `c1` (outside the `c1` cursor) but then `I` is NOT taking the updated value :( Any suggestions to make it working would be helpful, Thanks

```
create table t1(i int); 

create table t2(i int, j int);

insert into t1(i) values(1), (2), (3), (4), (5); 

insert into t2(i, j) values(1, 6), (2, 7), (3, 8), (4, 9), (5, 10);

delimiter $

CREATE PROCEDURE p1() 
BEGIN 
DECLARE I INT; 
DECLARE J INT;
DECLARE done INT DEFAULT 0;

DECLARE c1 CURSOR FOR SELECT i FROM t1;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;

OPEN c1;
REPEAT 
    FETCH c1 INTO I;

    IF NOT done THEN

        select I;

        DECLARE c2 CURSOR FOR 
            SELECT j FROM t2 WHERE i = I;

        OPEN c2;
        REPEAT
            FETCH c2 into J;

            IF NOT done THEN
                SELECT J;
            END IF;
        UNTIL done END REPEAT;
        CLOSE c2;

        set done = 0;

    END IF;

UNTIL done END REPEAT;

CLOSE c1;

END$

delimiter ;
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand what you are trying to do.  When you select individual fields one at a time in a procedure, you're creating multiple result sets.  I doubt that's what you want.

The following procedure is far simpler and gives you the same data in a single result set:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE p1()
BEGIN
  SELECT i, j FROM t1 JOIN t2 USING (i);
END
```

Perhaps you could edit your question and describe what result you want, or show an example of the desired output.

Comment: Thanks Bill. Yes we can use join but my question is can we do the same without using JOIN, but using two cursors.
Sometimes, the JOIN may be very costly in that case what is the solution?

Comment: It's a myth that join is costly.  Certainly it's hugely more efficient than doing *N+1* `SELECT` queries as you showed.